# core text - getting nsstring from ctrunref

Tags: ios, core-text

I have the following code to get a run:

```
        CFArrayRef runs = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);

        for(int j = 0; j < CFArrayGetCount(runs); j++)
        //for(id runObj in (__bridge NSArray*)CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line))
        {
            CTRunRef run = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runs, j);
}
```

What I need to do is to get the actual string of characters that contains this run.  If I get the glyphs then these are not actual characters, is there any way to for example get an nsstring containing the actual text given a ctrun?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
CTRunRef run = (CTRunRef)runObj;          
CFRange runRange = CTRunGetStringRange(run);
[[_attributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:NSMakeRange(runRange.location, runRange.length)] string]
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to get back the attributed string that was used in creation of a `CTRun`. Your program already ought to know this information, since it created the `CTFrame`, `CTLine` or `CTRun` from an attributed string.